Is there any disadvantage to putting join tables in their own schema?
Is there any disadvantage to putting join tables in their own schema?
Title, I could have a few schemas:

app

user
permission


app_join

user_permission



If I’m working with sql I’d have to include the full schema names which isn’t much of a difference, and if I use an orm I can call their relationship functions and bypass knowing about the schemas altogether. Is there any obvious downside with this setup? Anything that would only reveal itself at scale?

See my comment.

There would not be performance issues.
It would work fine as long as you do it on a smallish databases. "Smallish" here is a number of users connected to that database.
The reason why no one does that is that if you have two groups of users, one group should have access to a set of tables, and another does not - it is easier to connect groups with schemas, instead of searching all individual tables in different schemas.

Why "smallish" - surely there's no effect at all? Schemas are just a logical separation of tables - database company, schemas accounts_payable, accounts_recievable , hr... &c. The only implication for performance will be increased typing having to schema qualify tables that aren't in the public schema?

@Vérace No performance loss during execution of queries. But security administration tasks would be more difficult. And the less users in the database - the easier it would be - thus "smallish".

Hmmm... maybe, but one would only consider schemas for a "serious" system where one requires separation of concerns - you don't want somebody on the factory floor being able to see everyone in the company's salary! Perhaps more onerous, but no effect on the most important criterion - performance. I know the OP mentioned any disadvantages, so you're correct in that sense, but I would just suggest that when you're designing a serious system, these concerns are omnipresent.

Permissions management is good to point out! Our schemas are already split by use and we use group roles to manage permissions, so I don't think it would be as painful in this case.
